# tinyMCE strips "class"-attribute, although its in extended_valid_elements

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

tinyMCE keeps stripping the class-attribute of my element, when clicking "remove formatting", although i've added it to the extended_valid_elements. look here:

```
...
extended_valid_elements : "p[class],figure[class],figcaption",
valid_children : "+p[figure]",
...
```

all gets stripped. do you have any idea?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:formats (see the "remove format"-section).

You'll have to edit tiny_mce.js .
Search for the code shown there and add the following to the removeformat-array:

```
{selector : 'p', attributes : ['style'], split : false, expand : false, deep : true}
```

It should prevent tinymce from removing the class-attribute from p-elements when using the remove-format-button.

Comment: i dont know i got the markup right: i just want to make it possible, that the classes, that are appended to my figure elements wont get stripped. my code loooks as follows:

    ...
    extended_valid_elements : "p,figure[class],figcaption",
    formats : {
        figure: {selector : 'figure', attributes : ['class'], split : false, expand : false, deep : true}
    },
    ...

but the classes are stripped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

code must be:

```
...
formats : {
    removeformat : [
        {selector : 'figure', attributes : ['style'], split : false, expand : false, deep : true}
    ]
},
...
```